# NextJS function with lodash debounce is not working [TypeError: search(...) is undefined]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, lodash

I've been trying to make a component in NextJS that uses searches youtube based on input given. To reduce the number of API calls made, I'm using lodash debounce with the useCallback hook but I keep getting this error: `TypeError: search(...) is undefined`

Here's the code that I wrote:

```
export default function Player() {
  const [modalVisibility, setModalVisibility] = useState(true);

  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  const search = useCallback(
    debounce(async (keyword) => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/search/" + keyword); 
      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    }, 500),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchQuery) {
      search(searchQuery).then((results) => setSearchResults(results));
      console.log(searchQuery)
      console.log(searchResults)
    } else {
      setSearchResults([])
    }
  }, [searchQuery])


  return (
    <Modal label={'Search for videos'} show={modalVisibility} handleClose={() => setModalVisibility(false)}>
      <div>
        <IoSearch size='1.25em' color={searchQuery ? '#000' : '#9ca3af'}/>
        <input type="text" value={searchQuery} onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)} placeholder="eg: 'Standup Comedy'"/>
      </div>
      <SearchResults results={searchResults}/>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out why my search function is undefined?

Comment: I think useCallback is unneeded here - check out this example: https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/

Comment: @shanemacbride i removed the useCallback hook but still the error persists :[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debounce` does not return a value from inner function unless you specify `leading: true` option for it.

So it is not your `search` is undefined, but there is no promised and no `then(...)` returned from `search(...)` invocation.

Anyway I would suggest you to move your `setSearchResults` inside `search` function. You would still have race condition in case user types something and then quickly deletes query.

Answer (score 1):

To use the debounced `searchQuery`, you don't need to debounce the function that does the call, but rather debounce the searched value. You also don't need to wrap `fetch` function in a `React.useCallback` at all, just use it directly in your `useEffect`

I suggest using [`useDebounce`](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/) hook to debounce your search query.

```
 const debouncedSearchQuery = useDebounce(searchQuery, 500);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (debouncedSearchQuery) {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/search/${debouncedSearchQuery}`).then((data) => {
        console.log(debouncedSearchQuery);
        setSearchResults(data);
        console.log(searchResults);
      });
    } else {
      setSearchResults([]);
    }
  }, [debouncedSearchQuery]); // Only call effect if debounced search term changes
```